# box-decoration-break: clone not working on iOS Safari

Tags: html, css

I have a multiline text with a background surrounding the text. This works on every browser, but in iOS Safari 16.7.1 the padding-right is only visible on the last line. It seems to work fine on newer iOS Safari versions.

Is there a different approach how I could ensure that every line has the same padding-right?

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
}

.text {
  background-color: #f0f;
  display: inline;
  padding: 2px 12px;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <p class='text'>I am a very long text with multiple lines and background.</p>
</div>
```

On every browser the above code looks like this:[image]

On iOS Safari like this with padding-right only on the last line:
[image]